# Parsing badly formed HTML documents

Tags: java, c++, html, c

### HTML content:

```
<div id=xyz style="test" class=tt>
<p>Some data</p><br/>Blah blah blah
<input>
</div>
```

this will rendered as:

```
Some data

Blah blah blah
```

Here the html code is not well-formed, and I'm trying to get the text data as a simple string like this

```
string s="Some data\n\nblah blah blah";
```

No DOM nor SAX would help here.

### Question:

Are there any (C/C++ /Java) library available to parse non-well-formed HTML files?

Comment: Errr... HTML & XML? There are various extensions available to do HTML - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/ is one. Also [this](http://validator.w3.org/) site.

Comment: I thought HTML is derived of XML @Wilf

Comment: They are both Markup languages - that's why they both end in ML :) - I think they are both based on [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGML). I'm just a bit confused as most of the question refers to HTML, then goes onto XML...

Comment: There is nothing (or at least, there should not be) such as "malformed XML". "HTML" is historically way, way too forgiving; hence, the cross-over to XHTML. And, like XML, XHTML cannot be 'malformed' without stopping to be valid XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try out jsoup.http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document

Comment: PERFECT, that's just I was looking for, thanks dude :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend TagSoup ( http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/ ). Transforms poorly written HTML into nice XML.